# Permission problems prevent celery from running as daemon?

Tags: django, daemon, celery

I'm currently having some trouble running celery as daemon. I use apache to serve my Django application, so I set uid and gid in celery setting all as "www-data". There are 2 places I know so far that need access permission: `/var/log/celery/*.log`, `/var/run/celery/*.pid`, and I already set them owned by "www-data". However, celery couldn't get started when I run `sudo service celeryd start`. If I get rid of the --uid and --gid option for the command, celery could get started by user "root".

One other thing I noticed is that if I could start celery using "root", it will put some files like: `celery.bak`, `celery.dat`, `celery.dir` in my `CELERYD_CHDIR`, which is my django application directory. I also changed the application directory owned by "www-data", celery still couldn't get started. I copied all the setting files from another machine in which celery runs fine, so I suppose it's not my setting's problem. Does anyone have any clue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Su to celery user and start celery from the command line. Most likely you have an app log, not celery, that you need permission for.