# celery daemon - permission denied on log file

Tags: python, celery, daemon

I have been working on setting up my celery task as a daemon in order to process data on a schedule.

I have been following [the docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html) in order to set up my daemon, but have been running into a log file permission error that has me stumped.

Below is the configuration i have set up on an ubuntu box on Digital Ocean

/etc/default/celeryd

```
# here we have a single node
CELERYD_NODES="w1"

CELERY_BIN = "/mix_daemon/venv/bin/celery"
CELERYD_CHDIR="/mix_daemon/"

CELERYD_OPTS="-A tasks worker --loglevel=info --beat"

# %n will be replaced with the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERY_CREATE_RUNDIR=0
CELERY_CREATE_LOGDIR=0

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
```

however, when i run

```
sh -x /etc/init.d/celeryd start
```

i get the following error message:

```
celery multi v3.1.7 (Cipater)
> Starting nodes...
> celery@mix: OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/home/john/mix_daemon/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celeryd_detach.py", line 168, in <module> main()
File "/home/john/mix_daemon/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celeryd_detach.py", line 165, in main
detached_celeryd(app).execute_from_commandline()
File "/home/john/mix_daemon/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celeryd_detach.py", line 160, in execute_from_commandline
**vars(options)
File "/home/john/mix_daemon/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celeryd_detach.py", line 42, in detach
with detached(logfile, pidfile, uid, gid, umask, working_directory, fake):
File "/home/john/mix_daemon/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/platforms.py", line 314, in open
self.after_chdir()
File "/home/john/mix_daemon/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/platforms.py", line 384, in after_chdir_do
logfile and open(logfile, 'a').close()
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/celery/celery.log'
+ sleep 5
+ exit 0
```

I looked this error message up and saw [this answer](https://redmine.confine-project.eu/issues/97) from a redmine project.  So i tried the following to try to allow for the celery worker to write to the log file:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p -m 2755 /var/log/celery
$ sudo chown celery:celery /var/log/celery
```

but the same error remains when i try to start the daemon.

I am a celery noob, and any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12327331/538284

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> The init scripts can only be used by root, and the shell configuration file must also be owned by root"

So, you need to run:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/default/celeryd
```

and

```
sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start
```

By the way, you have invalid syntax in your celeryd config file:

```
CELERY_BIN = "/mix_daemon/venv/bin/celery"
```

spaces is not allowed with "=" operator, the correct is:

```
CELERY_BIN="/mix_daemon/venv/bin/celery"
```

Also check, that you have your bin in /mix_daemon not /home//mix_daemon

Answer (score 4):

It helps me:

```
sudo chown -R myuser:root /var/run/celery/
sudo chown -R myuser:root /var/log/celery/
```

Comment: This was necessary for me when using `systemd`, where `myuser` is whatever the User is set to in the `celery.service` file.

Answer (score 0):

**Tl;dr**

If you're using *systemd* for daemonization, your file `/etc/tmpfiles.d/celery.conf` should look like this:

```
d /run/celery 0755 myuser myusergroup -
d /var/log/celery 0755 myuser myusergroup -
```

**A little more detail**

For those using *systemd*, I found that I'd been using the wrong user when creating working directories for celery's logs and once I'd updated `/etc/tmpfiles.d/celery.conf` with the correct user and user group, my issues were solved.

The documentation mentions:

> You can also use systemd-tmpfiles in order to create working directories (for logs and pid).

> **file**: /etc/tmpfiles.d/celery.conf

And gives the example:

> ```
> d /run/celery 0755 celery celery -
> d /var/log/celery 0755 celery celery -
> ```

*Your* file should look like this:

```
d /run/celery 0755 myuser myusergroup -
d /var/log/celery 0755 myuser myusergroup -
```