# Celery not running (Permission Denied)

Tags: python, celery

I'm not running a Django Project, this is just a simple python project and I want to demonize the celery. Initially I was running it in the shell. Celery sometimes hangs in between(known issue). Hence I need to restart it again and again. Therefore, I need to daemonize it, so that I can run a script that restarts the celery on its own via a cronjob.

I've looked onto various [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736808/celery-daemon-permission-denied-on-log-file) on SO, but with no luck.

I've created a user and group , both named as  `celery` by following commands:-

```
sudo groupadd celery
sudo useradd -g celery celery
```

I created this file as: **/etc/default/celeryd**

```
CELERYD_NODES="w1"

CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"

CELERY_APP="tasks"

CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/cube26/Desktop/cube26/c26-quicklook"

CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8  -Q BBC,BGR,FASTCOMPANY"

CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE="celeryconfig" #I dont know what this is for?

CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1

CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
```

Then downloaded [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/celery/celery/3.1/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd) file and kept it inside  **/etc/init.d/celeryd**.

Then `chmod +x /etc/init.d/celeryd` to make it executable.

Thats all I did.

and I'm still getting an error saying `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/celery/w1.log'`

What wrong am I doing? Please help me rectify it.

Comment: what are permissions on directory `/var/log/celery` and who is the owner? The simplest way to check is run `ls -la /var/log/`

Comment: Since you asked for permission of `/var/log/celery` I did `ls -la /var/log/celery`, and it resulted it with the following output `drwxr-sr-x  2 celery celery 4096 Mar  3 11:56 .`  `drwxrwxr-x 23 root   syslog 4096 Mar  3 11:25 ..` ` -rw-r--r--  1 root   root      0 Mar  3 11:25 celery.log` `-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      0 Mar  3 11:29 w1.log`

Comment: you need to chown celery.celery w1.log

Comment: please remove `/var/log/celery/w1.log` or change it permisions: `chown -R celery:celery /var/log/celery/`

Comment: Still says the same `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/run/celery/w1.pid'`

Comment: No. now it show that You dont have permissions to create file inside `/var/run/celery/`. please also change perimisions

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Based on comments, You have wrong write permissions to log file.

Please change the ownership to `celery` using:

```
chown -R celery:celery /var/log/celery/
chown -R celery:celery /var/run/celery/
```

`-R` switch is used to change permissions recursive inside directory

Comment: Still says the same [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/run/celery/w1.pid'

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It made my day. Can you also please let me know whats the  use of `CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE="celeryconfig"` in the `/etc/default/celeryd` file? Just for extra knowledge.

Comment: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/application.html?highlight=celery_config_module#config-from-envvar

Answer (score 1):

you have create two file for this and give the permission for you pc user name

```
sudo mkdir -p -m 2755 /var/run/celery

sudo mkdir -p -m 2755 /var/log/celery

sudo chown $USER:$USER /var/run/celery

sudo chown $USER:$USER /var/log/celery
```

instead of **$USER** use your user name

Answer (score 0):

Tell celery where to put the `pid` file:

```
celery -A config --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}
```

where `CELERYD_PID_FILE` is `/var/www/my_site/celery.pid` for example.